# How to filter results based on age from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database setup with user info including name, email, dob, gender, website and other info.

I am trying to implement filter result options for the user page.

The problem is i don't know how to filter by age, since i am storing the age value as a date of birth, i have a php function to get age from it, but how do i go about this.

The filter option is age : 12-24, 25-32, 33-56 (in years)

How do i do like this? `select * from users where user.age <= 20 and >= 20` i don't even have a age column, all i have is date of birth.

The filter is stored in session variable `$_SESSION['age'] = 12-24` How do i get the first value (12) and the last value (24) from session and later filter so that the age should be greater than 12 and less than 24

Please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, dob) >= (12 * 365.25) AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, dob) <= (24 * 365.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar age:  a person born on `2016-02-28` is 0 years old on `2017-02-27` and 1 year old on `2017-02-28`.  A person born on `2016-02-29` is 0 years old on `2017-02-28` and 1 year old on `2017-03-01`. (Leap year).

MySQL's expresssion for this is

```
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, current_date)
```

It yields an integer, and handles the truncation and leap years correctly. (The 365.25 division of elapsed days does not necessarily get this right.)

Answer (score -1):

1. Subtract the birthdate from now to get the age, then compare that.
2. Use the value of the select (not the *text*, the *value*) as a lookup in an array to get the range of ages.

Comment: This helps a little, but can you in any ways please write and show it as in MySQL statement?

Comment: If you typed "mysql subtract two dates" into Google, the first result would be the MySQL manual page with the functions for doing that and many other things with dates.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (FLOOR((CURDATE() - `birthfield`) / 10000)) as `age` FROM `tablename` WHERE `age` <= 20 AND ..
```

Comment: 20101210 - 19760306 = 340904 .. i am only 34 though .. and didn't know `datediff`

Comment: I don't think MySQL will turn the dates into integers and subtract them like that, will it?

Comment: just tried that and it works .. but: i need to divide by 10000 *blush*

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get both value in diff variable then you should try this.

```
$sessArr = array();
$sessArr = explode('-',$_SESSION['age']);
```

now in the array `$sessArr` you have both value in array `$sessArr[0] and $sessArr[1].`
You can try this its may helpfull to you.

Answer (score -1):

that should work (haven't tested it')

> $_SESSION['age'] = "12-24";
>
> $agroup1 =
>   split($_SESSION['age'],'-');
>
> $min = $agroup1[0]; $max =
>   $agroup1[1];
>
> $query = " select * from users where
>   year(dob) <= year(curdate()) - 12 and
>   year(dob) >= year(curdate()) - 24 ";